# How to use a proxy with OpenURI

Tags: ruby, proxy, user-agent, open-uri

I'm trying to use OpenURI with a proxy and a user-agent string. I bought proxy list to use in my web scrapers.

Here's an example:

```
@src = open(url, "User-Agent"=> @agent,
  :proxy_http_basic_authentication => [
     "http://185.118.66.88:16506", "user", "password"]).read
```

Which resulted in:

```
!!! 502 Bad Gateway
```

I got a free proxy and used it and it worked, so I thought the problem might be in the username or password.

I tried the username and password I got from the company who sold me the proxy list.

If I try to use Nokogiri I get an error:

```
@src = Nokogiri::HTML(open(
   "http://google.com",
   :proxy_http_basic_authentication => [
     "http://#{@proxy}", "user", "password"]

 syntax error, unexpected keyword_rescue, expecting ')'
    rescue Exception => e
```

I want to create a class and use it for web scraping, Google for instance. It easily bans web-scrappers, so I will change the user-agent and proxy for each request.

Comment: This isn't a Nokogiri problem as Nokogiri doesn't care where the HTML comes from. It only reads the stream passed to it by OpenURI. The problem would be in your connection to the end host via the Proxy and OpenURI.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. The linked pages will help you understand how to work with Stack Overflow. Also, "[mcve]" and the linked page will help you write a more usable question. Your code example isn't syntactically correct nor does it show where a `rescue` would be in your code so we can't help diagnose that.

Comment: You can't write a generic scraper to be used on multiple sites. HTML isn't consistent enough between sites to allow that. Google won't be fooled by changing the proxy or user-agent settings; They understand how automated scraping works extremely well.

Comment: Don't change your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. If you get new information and need to ask a new question, you should....well... create a new question.

Comment: @piet.t OK I wont change question text anymore.

Comment: @the Tin Man About google. I will use pauses, and 27 000 proxies, and 5 different use agent. Each time for them I will be different man, as I understand. Yes I would try to use google API but I dont have working example.

Comment: That won't be good enough. Use their API. You're going against the flow, not with it.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you get 502 from *the target site*.

```
require 'open-uri'
@src = open("http://google.com",
            "User-Agent"=> 'Agent',
            proxy_http_basic_authentication: [
              "http://185.118.66.88:16506", "user", "password"]).read

#⇒ OpenURI::HTTPError: 407 Proxy Authentication Required
```

Which means everything goes as expected. Your attempt with Nokogiri requires two closing parentheses to work, but you’d better start with making plain `open` work, Nokogiri nevertheless relies on it.

Comment: Okay, but we talk about open-url first. And second. Can you share working example of Nokogiri with User Agent and Proxy (better if proxy will ask for username and password, but without good too)?